# how to add birthday from my application to my phone address book

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I have a task to develop the application related to address and access the birthdate from it. And if the user has to exists in the address then i can enter it manually from my application to address book.

I have to develop the application related to address book. From address book i have to get name,phone no,email, and birthday. so i can easily get it on my application. But for get i have set all thing from address book. But i also have to give facility to add the contact detail as above given field. and i can not find easily that how to add birthday in address book i have search a lot but i cant found it,

So,please help me and provide some sample code for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int recordId=123 //recordId in address book for record we want to update
//save birthday to address book
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID (addressBook,recordId);
CFErrorRef error = NULL; 

NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
//don't set year in address book (yyyy=1604)
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.1604",@"29.03"]];
[formatter release];

ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonBirthdayProperty,(CFDateRef)date, &error); 
ABAddressBookSave (addressBook,&error);
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Don't forget to import AddressBook/AddressBook.h file and add AddressBook.framework.

Comment: "1604" date is for date without defined year (only date/month)

Answer (score 1):

There is a demo app in Apple's code library called QuickContacts. You can download it and refer it. In that demo app there is a functionality where in you can create a new contact and it will save that contact in your iPhone's contacts.

Now, you can modify that controller and customize it as per your requirements. I didn't go down into the tiniest detail but I guess this would help you. You can download that demo app called QuickContacts from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475).

You might have to work a little bit but I hope it helps!